# How to create list of lists after every nth item

Tags: python

In python how can I create a list of lists after every 5th item?

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Expected output:

```
new_list = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']....]
```

Comment: See the `grouper` recipe here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
new_list = [my_list[i:i + 5] for i in xrange(0, len(my_list), 5)]
```

What's happening here is that takes chunks of data from 0 - 5, 5 - 10, etc. to create sub lists

Comment: How did you know the OP was using Python2

Comment: I didn't. I was using python 2

Comment: @JohnLaRooy How will it be different for Python3?

Comment: I think xrange is not an option

Comment: @Hannan, In Python3, you would need to use `range` instead of `xrange`

Comment: @JohnLaRooy Thx, I ended up fixing it myself.